# Can I use tkinter on PyScript?

Tags: tkinter, pyscript

I have a Python script that uses [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) to draw shapes. I have a problem running it in [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/).

The script is for a project that I want to present as a website but apparently some libraries including tkinter are disabled in PyScript.

Is there any way to use tkinter on PyScript?

Comment: Checkout [pyscriptgui](https://pyscriptgui.wordpress.com/). It's based on tkinter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyScript is based on Pyodide, so you can use Python-only packages from PyPi and parts of the standard library that is available in Pyodide [as explained in PyScript FAQ](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/faq.html#what-packages-can-i-use-can-i-use-anything-from-pypi).

However, Pyodide does not include tkinter and it is listed in the [Removed modules](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/wasm-constraints.html#removed-modules) section of its documentation.

So it is currently not possible to use tkinter in PyScript.

Comment: This is correct - tkinter is not available in Pyodide for a variety of reasons. However, if all you need to do is draw shapes, you can draw them directly onto a \<canvas\> html element [like in this example](https://jeff.glass/post/7-guis-pyscript/#circle-header), or use an intermediate library like [p5js](https://p5js.org/) that you import into PyScript.